# Selecting a certificate automatically using TEmbeddedWB in Delphi

Tags: delphi, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, twebbrowser

I'm a developer of a software where users can access different websites fast and automatically fill all fields with user's information, but some of these websites require a client certificate.

So, the problem is... We don't want to show that certificate selection window and automatically select a certificate.

The user can select the certificate before accessing the websites, so we already have certificate information.

I'm using TEmbeddedWB and its event OnShowMessage to prevent showing unnecessary dialogs, but Silent property is FALSE. I found something using OnQueryService with IHTTPSecurity interface but this event wasn't called...

Do you know what I can do to automatically select a certificate without asking the user to select?

Comment: Take a look at SecurityManager.pas in the TEmbeddedWB source, you want to react to `URLACTION_CLIENT_CERT_PROMPT` and respond with `URLPOLICY_ALLOW` to suppress the dialog. Please note that it will only work if you have only one or no certificates installed. More info can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537178(v=vs.85)